# Monotouch.Dialog iOS 7 automatic look and feel upgrade?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog, ios7

I'm developing my first iOS app in Xamarin.iOS, using MonoTouch.Dialog to create the graphical user interface via code with only minor (color only) customizations.

My question is: Will the user interface upgrade to the new iOS 7 look & feel for users using that iOS version or it will always look the same regardless?

I don't have an Apple Developer Account yet so I'm not able to install iOS 7 to try it in my iOS device and haven't found documentation regarding this particular topic in MonoTouch.Dialog website.

Comment: I have created a small sample that just create new Monotouch Dialog RootElement with some sections in Grouped mode and it still look like on io6. SDK is set to ios7, target to ios7. So it looks, no, it will not upgrade look and feel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, when Xamarin.iOS 7.0 is out, when you set target SDK to 7.0, everything looks iOS7 like.

Answer (score 3):

**iOS agnostic answer**: MonoTouch.Dialog uses `UITableView` (and friends) and will behave like any other application, using `UITableView`, would using the same iOS version.

At this time information about **iOS 7** is only available under NDA so you unlikely to get any public answers. Apple private forums, where you can ask iOS 7 specific questions, requires you to have a developer account (which ensure you're covered by the same NDA as everyone else).